# How to change password

Tags: password

I have a blog. My computer crashed months ago, my username is `admin` I have tried to recover my password but as it is lost create a new one, they sent a huge long address password will not let me copy and I just do not know what to do. I have recently paid for hosting the site again and can't use my dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your admin's user name (or email address), then use that on the 'lost password' screen. Then click on the link in the email you will get to change it.

BTW, a user called 'admin' is not really good practice. That is halfway to getting the credentials for your site, but some 'rainbow attacks' that try to guess your password. I never use a user called 'admin', especially with an admin-level access. (Sometimes I demote that user to 'subscriber' just to irritate hackers to spending their time on it. But only after creating and logging in as the new admin-level user.)

If necessary, and you have phpMyAdmin access, you can go to the wp-users table and set the password there. (Or change the email account associated with that user, then use 'lost password'.) But using the 'lost password' thing is faster and a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question related to wordpress dashboard admin access, if yes

### Two ways you can reset

if you remember email address ( admin email ) you can simply click on forgot password and enter there relevant email address and there you'll get reset link.

#### If you have database access like phpmyadmin follow steps below:

- login to phpmyadmin
- find your site's database. ( e.g., wp_dbname )
- find the table row named wp_users, click on it
         then you will need to choose the username you want to change the password for
- click on edit, there you will see user_login and user_pass fields
         enter new user name and password ( in case of password field, you will see numbers, ignore them and delete all the letters from
  there and then enter your desired password. remember the letters are
  case sensitive ) and Select MD5 from dropdown for password field.

If you have problem in logging to phpmyadmin ( forgot username and password for the particular database ), you can find the info in the wp-config.php file which is located in your wordpress site's root directory. You can access this file from ftp:

## find

```
define('DB_NAME', 'your_dbname');

define('DB_USER', 'user_name');

define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password_for_phpmyadmin');

define('DB_HOST', 'db_server');
```

I hope this helps.